# Show aggregate report info in console when running jmeter tests with mvn

Tags: maven, jmeter, report, aggregate, summary

I have a mvn project in which is also integrated jmeter, to test performance. So far I have 6 thread groups in my test plan, all of them contains HTTP Requests. I run the tests using the command "mvn clean verify" from jmeter-maven plugin. Among the results I found multiple rows like this:

summary +   1 in 00:00:02 =   0.6/s Avg: 208 Min: 208 Max: 208 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 6 Started: 12 Finished: 6

I would need some extra information in console, especially the name and the avg time of each thread group or of the HTTP Request that ran. For example, something similar with aggregate report from GUI mode :

Label           Samples Average Median 90% Line 95% Line 99% Line Min Max ...

AppleCodeRequest    6   196      119    279      284       284    108 284
PearCodeRequest      3   382      485    490      490       490    173 490

I want this because I am using a sh script to run the tests and I would like to trigger some performance issues before opening the html reports.

Is there any way to obtain this? Maybe some user properties (even if I searched for one and no result) or some workaround ?

Comment: I understand you want in your IDE console. But why not use Jmeter's own reports. Jmeter has tons of reports that it can generate in numerous formats as well (csv, html etc) and contain all the details you are looking for + much more

Comment: I am using a sh script that contains that command to run the tests and I would like to trigger some performance issues before opening the html reports. And to do that I only have access to that "console" text, resulted from mvn command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is going for a plugin like [BlazeMeter Uploader](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/BlazeMeterUploader.md), this way you will be able to observe real time test metrics in a fancy web UI. You can install BlazeMeter Uploader plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

---

Alternative solution would be using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/).

1. Add the next lines to your *pom.xml* file

   ```
   <configuration>
       <jmeterExtensions>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.2</artifact>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-synthesis:2.2</artifact>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-dummy:0.2</artifact>
           <artifact>kg.apc:cmdrunner:2.0</artifact>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-filterresults:2.2</artifact>
           <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.6</artifact>
       </jmeterExtensions>
       <!-- The plugin uses some broken dependencies
            An alternative is to set this to true and use excludedArtifacts, see below
       -->
       <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
       <propertiesJMeter>
           <jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush>
       </propertiesJMeter>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Add another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan with 1 user and infinite number of loops
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Thread Group
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   def resultFile = new File('../results').list().first()
   "java -jar ../lib/ext/cmdrunner-2.0.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv temp.csv  --input-jtl ../results/$resultFile --plugin-type AggregateReport".execute().waitFor()
   println("cat temp.csv".execute().text)
   new File("temp.csv").delete()
   ```
5. Control how frequently you want to see this info using i.e. [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)
6. You should be able to see the results in the console window:

   [image]